# Marking Integers Using a Wheel

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, prime-numbers

Suppose I had a wheel of diameter one meter and I was charged with marking every meter along an infinite stretch of a beach. The strategy is to insert pegs into the wheel so that every point that is a distance of $z$ meters from where I started, with $z$ an integer, will have a depression in it once I've passed, rolling the wheel over it. Will the pegs cover the entire wheel or none of it? I've realized already that marking every $p$-th meter, with $p$ a prime would accomplish the same thing and believe that the question is fundamentally asking what the measure of the integers modulo $2\pi$ is. Proofs please!

Comment: Since $\pi$ is irrational, the whole wheel would be covered. If only a finite number of pegs were on the wheel, that would make $2\pi$ a rational number, which it clearly is not.

Comment: But the question is not whether we have a finite number of pegs it's what the measure of this set of pegs will be.

Comment: Guessing here, the Lebesgue measure will be 0, since you can 'count' each discrete peg. I'm at loss for a proof I'm afraid.

Comment: That was my intuition as well. Unfortunately, the proof that the rationals on [0,1] are of measure zero is decidedly different in spirit since, although these pegs are countable (intuitively) they are all of irrational coordinate.

Comment: @Archaick: The proof is no different. You’re inserting only countably many pegs. Unwind the wheel, and the pegs are a countable subset of $[0,\pi)$. Every countable subset has Lebesgue measure $0$. (The subset is dense, but that’s irrelevant to its measure.)